# hide-show functionality using css

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp-2.0

I am working on hide show functionality using JavaScript

but it occurring error on console for onclick function

I am not getting why this error occurring.

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

$page = '0';

$output.='<div id="my_section" style="display:none;">This is my section</div>';

echo $output;

?>
```

I page-id is grater than 0 need to display block of div my_section

e.g.

```
$output.='<div id="my_section" if($page>\'0\') { style="display:none;" } else { style="display:block;" }>This is my section</div>';
```

i am not getting how to add this condition in php please help

Comment: post your js code also what is my_section and icon ? is that one is php varriable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($page > 0) { 
    $style = 'style="display:none;"'; 
} else {
    $style = 'style="display:block;"'; 
}

$output.='<div id="my_section" ' . $style . '>This is my section</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
<?php

    $page = '0';
    $output.='<div class="span6"> 
    <div class="header" onclick="showtabs(my_section,icon);">
    <h1>My Section <span class="iconc" id="icon">+</span></h1>
    </div></div>';

    if($page > 0){

    $output.='<div id="my_section" style="display:block;">This is my section</div>';

    } else {
    $output.='<div id="my_section" style="display:none;">This is my section</div>';
    }

    echo $output;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your conditional logic outside of the string, eg:

```
$display = ($page > 0)? 'none' : 'block';
$output.='<div id="my_section" style="display:' . $display . ';">This is my section</div>';
```

Or longer but perhaps clearer:

```
output.='<div id="my_section"';

if($page>0) 
{ 
    output.= 'style="display:none;"';
} 
else {
    output.= 'style="display:block;"';
}

output.= '>This is my section</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$output.='<div id="my_section" ';
if($page > 0) { 
    $output .= 'style="display:none;"';
} else {
    $output .= 'style="display:block;"';
}
$output .= '>This is my section</div>';
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as @user574632!

Comment: Sorry, actually when i start to answere, there is no answere available. And after i post my answere i know this.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest variant

```
$display = ($page > 0) ? 'style="display:none;"' : 'style="display:block;"';
$output .= "<div id=\"my_section\" {$display}>This is my section</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if` condition we can use `Ternary Logic`. This will makes coding simple `if/else` logic quicker and make code shorter

```
$style = ($page>0)?'style="display:none"':'style="display:block"';
echo '<div id="my_section" '.$style.' >This is my section</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you have done, problem is that you insert your PHP code like if was text.

```
$output.='<div id="my_section" if($page>\'0\') { style="display:none;" } else { style="display:block;" }>This is my section</div>';
```

To make it work you can use [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).
So it will work if you write it like that (to stay in same way you try to do it) :

```
$output.='<div id="my_section" style="display: '.($page > 0 ? 'none' : 'block').';">This is my section</div>';
```